# CSS (opacity transition) working on my test site but not real site

Tags: css

I have an opacity transition (when you hover over the slider) that works on my test site but not on the client's site. When I inspect the element (.img-overlay) it doesn't show the CSS.

The site: http://wearepaperpeople.com/

Here's my code:

```
.feat-item {
   position:relative;
   height:660px;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   display:block;
   width:100%;
   padding:17.2% 32.5%;
}
.img-overlay {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   opacity: 0;
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fae615,#2e9a9c);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fae615,#2e9a9c);
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fae615,#2e9a9c);
   background-image: linear-gradient(top,#fae615,#2e9a9c);
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.img-overlay:hover {
   opacity: .6;
}
```

Comment: Can't see the styles declared for `.img-overlay`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did inspect the code on the website and the code you have mentioned. It seems that the stylesheet hasn't been uploaded properly to the server or some other issue. Also add transition to image-overlay and make it background instead of background-image.

```
.feat-item {
  position:relative;
   height:660px;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   display:block;
   width:100%;
   padding:17.2% 32.5%;
}
.img-overlay {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   opacity: 0;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fae615,#2e9a9c);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fae615,#2e9a9c);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fae615,#2e9a9c);
   background: linear-gradient(top,#fae615,#2e9a9c);
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .img-overlay:hover {
       opacity: .6;
    }
```

Comment: Ahhhh yes... I was adding an effect on a theme they installed and you have to enter custom CSS in a field. Not used to working that way! Thank you.

I changed it to background but do you mean I should change something about transition too? Or is that part OK?

Comment: Other stuff seems fine.